# OPENCV+KIVY+BUILDOZER ON ANDROID PHONE

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to use opencv, kivy and buildzer to build an app on my android phone. I could debug successully the app and build to android phone. But when I open the app, the camera is not working.
But after building this code with buildozer for android, when I open the App it shows a black screen with a small square in the left corner of the screen. Anyone can help me? I believe the camera is not being accessed.

If you have any recommend or another way to do it, please let me know.

Thank You!

Here is the code I am using:

```
# coding:utf-8
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2


class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        return self.my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working through this as well. I have found that you need to add a couple lines to request permission from the android device. These should be included at build. Currently I cannot access the selfie cam so I think you need to remove the 1 from `self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`.

Reference: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1004

```py
# coding:utf-8
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2
from android.permissions import request_permissions # Added import


class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Give the app permissions to communicate
        request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA,
                             Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
                             Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,])
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture() # Removed the 1
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
        return self.my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

Comment: Build was successful. However, the app shows a blank white screen only. Tried setting VideoCapture(0), it works on Ubuntu but APK does not. Same blank white screen.

Comment: @KukilKashyapBorgohain Did you check permissions?

Comment: Yes. A 100% sure. I am using Ubuntu 22.04, minocanda python 3.10, ( but android build virtual environment is using python 3.9, should not be a problem I suppose). OpenCV 4.5.1, kivy 1.9.0. Are you able to build it currently?

Comment: @KukilKashyapBorgohain Check the buildozer logs. Try switching to 3.9 as well.

Comment: Checked the build log. Although the build was successful, I can observe two things.
1. supported SDK warning.
2. Unable to strip the following libraries.  


ugDeb Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libSDL2.so, libSDL2_image.so, libSDL2_mixer.so, libSDL2_ttf.so, libcrypto1.1.so, libffi.so, libimage_processing_util_jni.so, libmain.so, libopencv_calib3d.so, libopencv_core.so, libopencv_dnn.so, libopencv_features2d.so, libopencv_flann.so,  libpython3.9.so, libsqlite3.so, libssl1.1.so.